# Ending a sentence with the noun, disapproval

Tags: nouns

Could I end a sentence with the word, disapproval? As in the paragraph below.

"Actually, I could imagine that happening. He conceivably released the shark that killed him and it gnawed at someone. He was incarcerated for it, but had to fake his death so nobody found out. But, Janet and Gaz could rekindle their affair and Johnny could appear as a ghost to show his disapproval."

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can finish a sentence with disapproval. I have issues with your text but that is not what you asked.

Comment: "Yes - there is no problem with finishing sentences with a **noun**."

Comment: Why would this not be allowed??

Comment: In agreement with Bruce Murray, I have issues with almost everything in your text EXCEPT your usage of the word "disapproval" at the end of your sentence. :)

Comment: Wow. These commenters are really showing their disapproval.

Comment: Why do you think there might be a problem with ending the sentence with "disapproval"?